# Ecommerce software - what do I need to do to split orders up and whats the best OS software to do it?

Tags: php, e-commerce

I have a niche website which sells souvenirs. At the moment my catalog consists of just what we have in the shop. However there are some high value (like crystal) products from a bunch of different suppliers which I'd like to be able to offer but not actually hold stock of.

Therefore when someone orders a whopping huge crystal vase and a fridge magnet I need to be able to seamlessly detect that parts of the order need to be directed towards different suppliers.

At the moment I use zencart so I'm obviously going to have to custom code it (unless someone can suggest a cart which has this feature?) but I can't quite get my head around what I need to do.

I've been learning php for months now and I consider I'm ready to have a stab at this but as I say I'm confused about exactly where to start.

Can anybody provide me with some direction on how to do this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a work of reference, not a forum. Please don't use emoticons in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon your design decision how you want to show those thrird party products.There are number of options

1. Provide links to the third party products directly.
2. Store there SKU's in your system and do some post order processing.

There are number of E-commerce site which have different business models.Some of them store product information in there system and tend to have some SKU/ProdutID by which they can easily find out the supplier.

How you will deliver that product decides the further model.In All when the order will be placed all you need to have separate that line-item (third pat product) from the Order and need to send that details to the supplier.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for answering but boo for being one of the ones who closed my question ;) (only messing)

Comment: :)  your question was too generic and SO has certain principals.i suggest next time put for information in your question :)